# Incrementing numerical values in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I would love some help with this problem I am having an issue in Excel I am trying to pull fill a formula that I have written to advance the value of the cells being counted. What my formula does is check each cell to see if the letter p is in the cell, and if so it counts up for every cell that it searches and outputs the total in the cell the formula is in, pretty simple.

This is the pattern for the formula that I have created.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"K1","N1","Q1","T1","W1","Z1","AC1","AF1"}),"*p*"))
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"K2","N2","Q2","T2","W2","Z2","AC2","AF2"}),"*p*"))
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"K3","N3","Q3","T3","W3","Z3","AC3","AF3"}),"*p*"))
```

For some reason this will not AutoFill when I pull down the cell.

I have thought about perhaps writing a python script to increment the values but am not that familiar with how to do this within Python.

Does anyone here have an idea in how I could achieve the repeated formula without having to manually type it in each cell? I am trying to normalize a "Database" and this is the only way that I am able to normalize level 3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the cells you are querying appear to be consistently spaced apart: `=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("p",K1:AF1))),N(MOD(COLUMN(K1:AF1)-MIN(COLUMN(K1:AF1)),3)=0))`. This can be simplified if you have O365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Countif requires the first argent to be a range, therefore it errors. The following function does work:
`=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("p",CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},K1,N1,Q1,T1,W1,Z1,AC1,AF1)))))`

Answer (score -1):

A bit hard to follow  without seeing a few example values of k1 n1 etc but it might be worth adding in the address formula =ADDRESS()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).